# Как сделать PIVOT таблицы с двумя столбцами

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pivot

Есть таблица в Pandas:

```
  Название  Значение
0        А        25
1        А        15
2        А        14
3        Б        36
4        Б        47
5        Б        67
6        В        16
7        В        95
8        В        47
```

Какой функцией его можно быстро перегруппировать чтоб получилось:

```
    А   Б   В
0  25  36  16
1  15  47  95
2  14  67  47
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы вы привели свой код -  что конкретно у вас не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res = (df.pivot(columns = "Название", values="Значение")
      .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna()
      .values.astype("int"))).rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

```
    А   Б   В
0  25  36  16
1  15  47  95
2  14  67  47
```

Answer (score 2):

```
res = (df
       .assign(x=df.groupby("Название").cumcount())
       .pivot_table(index="x", columns="Название", values="Значение")
       .rename_axis(None, axis=0)
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

---

результат:

```
In [31]: res
Out[31]:
    А   Б   В
0  25  36  16
1  15  47  95
2  14  67  47
```

Comment: Сработало)) а как сделать чтоб убрать еще две подписи "название" и "х" с таблицы?

Comment: @AlihanUrumov, дополнил ответ